# Permission denied (publickey) Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a repository in Bitbucket, and I can't clone it, because I'm getting

> Permission denied (publickey).

I have generated the SSH key and added it in my Bitbucket account settings. I have set my git username and password.

I've tried running this command:

```
ssh git@bitbucket.org
```

And I got this:

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address
>   '104.192.143.2' to the list of known hosts.
>
> PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
>
> logged in as coffeejunkie.
>
> You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is
>   disabled. Connection to bitbucket.org closed.

coffeejunkie is my Bitbucket username, so I have logged in successfully.

But permission is still denied. What else am I missing?

UPD:

`-vvv git@bitbucket.org` gives following:

> OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016 debug1:
>   Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug1:
>   /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for * debug2: resolving
>   "bitbucket.org" port 22 debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0 debug1:
>   Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.192.143.2] port 22. debug1:
>   Connection established. debug1: identity file /home/coffee/.ssh/id_rsa
>   type 1 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1:
>   identity file /home/coffee/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 debug1:
>   key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /home/coffee/.ssh/id_dsa type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such file
>   or directory debug1: identity file /home/coffee/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type
>   -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1: identity file /home/coffee/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /home/coffee/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /home/coffee/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such
>   file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /home/coffee/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1 debug1: Enabling
>   compatibility mode for protocol 2.0 debug1: Local version string
>   SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 debug1: Remote protocol
>   version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.0.311-c6337e4 app-134
>   debug1: no match: conker_1.0.311-c6337e4 app-134 debug2: fd 3 setting
>   O_NONBLOCK debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git' debug3:
>   hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/coffee/.ssh/known_hosts" debug3:
>   record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file
>   /home/coffee/.ssh/known_hosts:1 debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
>   from bitbucket.org debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs:
>   ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa debug3:
>   send packet: type 20 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent debug3: receive
>   packet: type 20 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received debug2: local client
>   KEXINIT proposal debug2: KEX algorithms:
>   curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
>   debug2: host key algorithms:
>   ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
>   debug2: ciphers ctos:
>   chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
>   debug2: ciphers stoc:
>   chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
>   debug2: MACs ctos:
>   umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
>   debug2: MACs stoc:
>   umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
>   debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib debug2:
>   compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib debug2: languages ctos: 
>   debug2: languages stoc:  debug2: first_kex_follows 0  debug2: reserved
>   0  debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal debug2: KEX algorithms:
>   curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
>   debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa debug2: ciphers ctos:
>   aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128
>   debug2: ciphers stoc:
>   aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128
>   debug2: MACs ctos:
>   hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
>   debug2: MACs stoc:
>   hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
>   debug2: compression ctos: none debug2: compression stoc: none debug2:
>   languages ctos:  debug2: languages stoc:  debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
>   debug2: reserved 0  debug1: kex: algorithm:
>   curve25519-sha256@libssh.org debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
>   debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC:
>   hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none debug1: kex:
>   client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
>   compression: none debug3: send packet: type 30 debug1: expecting
>   SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY debug3: receive packet: type 31 debug1: Server
>   host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
>   debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/coffee/.ssh/known_hosts"
>   debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file
>   /home/coffee/.ssh/known_hosts:1 debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
>   from bitbucket.org debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file
>   "/home/coffee/.ssh/known_hosts" debug3: record_hostkey: found key type
>   RSA in file /home/coffee/.ssh/known_hosts:4 debug3: load_hostkeys:
>   loaded 1 keys from 104.192.143.2 debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known
>   and matches the RSA host key. debug1: Found key in
>   /home/coffee/.ssh/known_hosts:1 debug3: send packet: type 21 debug2:
>   set_newkeys: mode 1 debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks debug1:
>   SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS debug3:
>   receive packet: type 21 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 debug1: rekey
>   after 4294967296 blocks debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received debug2: key:
>   /home/coffee/.ssh/id_rsa (0x560e427ce090), agent debug2: key:
>   /home/coffee/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)) debug2: key:
>   /home/coffee/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)) debug2: key:
>   /home/coffee/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)) debug3: send packet: type 5
>   debug3: receive packet: type 6 debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received debug3: send packet: type 50
>   debug3: receive packet: type 51 debug1: Authentications that can
>   continue: publickey debug3: start over, passed a different list
>   publickey debug3: preferred
>   gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
>   debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey debug3: remaining preferred:
>   keyboard-interactive,password debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
>   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey debug1: Offering RSA
>   public key: /home/coffee/.ssh/id_rsa debug3: send_pubkey_test debug3:
>   send packet: type 50 debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for
>   reply debug3: receive packet: type 60 debug1: Server accepts key:
>   pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279 debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp
>   SHA256:D24jvbjnHDP1iBckX6x4xv861x6AL/DbEwW0asiYUG8 debug3:
>   sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA
>   SHA256:D24jvbjnHDP1iBckX6x4xv861x6AL/DbEwW0asiYUG8 debug3: send
>   packet: type 50 debug3: receive packet: type 52 debug1: Authentication
>   succeeded (publickey). Authenticated to bitbucket.org
>   ([104.192.143.2]:22). debug1: channel 0: new [client-session] debug3:
>   ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0 debug2: channel 0: send open debug3:
>   send packet: type 90 debug1: Entering interactive session. debug1:
>   pledge: network debug3: receive packet: type 91 debug2: callback start
>   debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set
>   IP_TOS 0x10 debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0 debug2: channel 0:
>   request pty-req confirm 1 debug3: send packet: type 98 debug1: Sending
>   environment. debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER
>   = lv_LV.UTF-8 debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0 debug3: send packet: type 98 debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = lv_LV.UTF-8 debug2:
>   channel 0: request env confirm 0 debug3: send packet: type 98 debug3:
>   Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID debug3: Ignored env XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR
>   debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = lv_LV.UTF-8 debug2: channel 0:
>   request env confirm 0 debug3: send packet: type 98 debug3: Ignored env
>   CLUTTER_IM_MODULE debug3: Ignored env SESSION debug3: Ignored env
>   GPG_AGENT_INFO debug3: Ignored env TERM debug3: Ignored env
>   VTE_VERSION debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX debug3: Ignored env
>   SHELL debug3: Ignored env QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON debug3:
>   Ignored env WINDOWID debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = lv_LV.UTF-8
>   debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0 debug3: send packet: type 98
>   debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_SESSION debug3:
>   Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
>   debug3: Ignored env USER debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS debug3: Ignored
>   env QT_ACCESSIBILITY debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = lv_LV.UTF-8
>   debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0 debug3: send packet: type 98
>   debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_PATH debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT_PATH
>   debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
>   debug3: Ignored env DEFAULTS_PATH debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
>   debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION debug3: Ignored env PATH debug3:
>   Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE debug3: Ignored env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
>   debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = lv_LV.UTF-8 debug2: channel 0:
>   request env confirm 0 debug3: send packet: type 98 debug3: Ignored env
>   XDG_SESSION_TYPE debug3: Ignored env PWD debug3: Ignored env JOB
>   debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_PID
>   debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8 debug2: channel 0: request env
>   confirm 0 debug3: send packet: type 98 debug3: Ignored env GDM_LANG
>   debug3: Ignored env MANDATORY_PATH debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT
>   = lv_LV.UTF-8 debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0 debug3: send packet: type 98 debug3: Ignored env COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE debug3:
>   Ignored env IM_CONFIG_PHASE debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION debug3:
>   Ignored env SESSIONTYPE debug3: Ignored env GTK2_MODULES debug3:
>   Ignored env SHLVL debug3: Ignored env HOME debug3: Ignored env
>   XDG_SEAT debug3: Ignored env LANGUAGE debug3: Ignored env
>   GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_INSTANCE debug3:
>   Ignored env UPSTART_EVENTS debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
>   debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME debug3: Ignored env COMPIZ_BIN_PATH
>   debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS debug3: Ignored env
>   XDG_DATA_DIRS debug3: Ignored env QT4_IM_MODULE debug3: Ignored env
>   LESSOPEN debug3: Ignored env INSTANCE debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_JOB
>   debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
>   debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP debug3: Ignored env
>   GTK_IM_MODULE debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE debug1: Sending env
>   LC_TIME = lv_LV.UTF-8 debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0 debug3:
>   send packet: type 98 debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = lv_LV.UTF-8 debug2:
>   channel 0: request env confirm 0 debug3: send packet: type 98 debug3:
>   Ignored env XAUTHORITY debug3: Ignored env _ debug2: channel 0:
>   request shell confirm 1 debug3: send packet: type 98 debug2: callback
>   done debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
>   debug3: receive packet: type 100 debug2: channel_input_status_confirm:
>   type 100 id 0 PTY allocation request failed on channel 0 debug3:
>   receive packet: type 99 debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99
>   id 0 debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0 logged in as
>   coffeejunkie.
>
> You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is
>   disabled. debug3: receive packet: type 98 debug1:
>   client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0 debug3:
>   receive packet: type 96 debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof debug2: channel 0:
>   output open -> drain debug2: channel 0: obuf empty debug2: channel 0:
>   close_write debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed debug3: receive
>   packet: type 97 debug2: channel 0: rcvd close debug2: channel 0:
>   close_read debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed debug3: channel 0:
>   will not send data after close debug2: channel 0: almost dead debug2:
>   channel 0: gc: notify user debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
>   debug2: channel 0: send close debug3: send packet: type 97 debug2:
>   channel 0: is dead debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting debug1:
>   channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1 debug3: channel 0:
>   status: The following connections are open:   #0 client-session (t4 r0
>   i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)
>
> debug3: send packet: type 1 Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
>   Transferred: sent 3508, received 1836 bytes, in 0.3 seconds Bytes per
>   second: sent 12053.3, received 6308.4 debug1: Exit status 0

Comment: Can you run `ssh -vvv git@bitbucket.org` and update the log

Comment: @PseudoAj done.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76716171/2126077

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't run a raw `ssh` command on most services like GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab:

> You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. ***Shell access is disabled.***

This message indicates that you've successfully connected to Bitbucket. However, they don't use `bash` or another shell for the `git` user. They likely use a custom [git-shell](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell) instead, which only allows `git` commands.

Use `git clone git@bitbucket.org/path/to/your/repository` instead of `ssh`. Keep in mind that you have to create the repository beforehand.

Comment: @YawningMilk No, that's a) not necessary and b) would make all owner's repository available to you. I guess it's a misconfiguration at that point.

Comment: my bad, I was trying to do sudo git clone all the time. Without sudo everything works as it should

Answer (score 9):

I have this issue on my Mac a lot caused by my SSH agent not retaining the SSH key I have setup. Have not figured out to make it persist, but per this troubleshooting site https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/troubleshoot-ssh-issues/ here is how I fix it:

From the terminal

Check to see if your SSH key is loaded:

```bash
$ ssh-add -l
```

If you don't see your key listed, add it by entering ssh-add followed by the path to the private key file:

```bash
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/<private_key_file>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a SSH Key:

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/

Then, paste your new SSH public key in your profile settings from Bitbucket:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/permission-denied-publickey-302811860.html

Easy peasy!

Comment: When ever I see "easy peasy" or even just "simply" I seethe. I have the same problem. Set up a new branch and the commands to fetch and checkout get permission errors. It works fine with the old branches, just not with the new. and the fix is to "simply" run git fetch.